# Untangling subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a rather complex query that returns a single row, and I'd like to extend it to return multiple rows, one for each region. Right now, I can use the following query to get stats for one region at a time (in the example, the 'West' region):

```
SELECT Count(id)       totalcustomers,
       Sum(ordertotal) totaldollars
FROM   (SELECT c.*
        FROM   customers c
               JOIN customeraddresses ca
                 ON c.id = ca.customerid
        WHERE  ca.state IN (SELECT state
                            FROM   stateregions
                            WHERE  region = "West")
        GROUP  BY c.id) t
```

I would like to get a summary table for all regions at once: the first column should have the region names, and then the other columns should have the summary stats, as they already do.

***A running example is available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/297e86/5***

In case something goes wrong with SQLFiddle, here's the data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    (
     id INT, 
     ordertotal INT,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

INSERT INTO customers
(id, ordertotal)
VALUES
(1, 100),
(2, 250),
(3, 120);


CREATE TABLE customeraddresses (
  customerid INT,
  state char(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (customerid,state)
);

INSERT INTO customeraddresses
(customerid, state)
VALUES
(1, 'ca'),
(2, 'ny'),
(3, 'ny'),
(3, 'ca');

CREATE TABLE stateregions (
  region varchar(20),
  state char(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (region,state)
);

INSERT INTO stateregions
(region, state)
VALUES
('West', 'ca'),
('East', 'ny');
```

Obviously, the structure and values have been greatly simplified for this example, so please ask if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` to the `stateregions` table, and then `GROUP BY` the region:

```
  SELECT region, count(id) totalcustomers,sum(ordertotal) totaldollars
  FROM customers c 
    JOIN customeraddresses ca ON c.id = ca.customerid
    JOIN stateregions s on ca.state = s.state
  GROUP BY s.region
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/297e86/15)

This will return you one row for each region:

```
REGION  TOTALCUSTOMERS  TOTALDOLLARS
East    2               370
West    2               220
```

---

In lieu of potential duplicates, a subquery with `distinct` should work for you:

```
SELECT region, COUNT(id), SUM(ordertotal)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.ordertotal, s.region
  FROM customers c 
      JOIN customeraddresses ca ON c.id = ca.customerid
      JOIN stateregions s on ca.state = s.state
  ) t
GROUP BY region
```

Resulting in:

```
REGION  TOTALCUSTOMERS  TOTALDOLLARS
All     3               470
East    2               370
West    2               220
```

Comment: What if we had an "All" region though that included both East and West? Then we'd have double-counting for that region. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/737ce5/6

Answer (score 0):

turn each subquery into an inner join

```
SELECT Count(id)       totalcustomers,
       Sum(ordertotal) totaldollars
        FROM   customers c
               JOIN customeraddresses ca
                 ON c.id = ca.customerid
 inner join stateregions sr on sr.state = ca.state
```

where sr.region ="WEST"

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because customers have multiple addresses.  Hence, they can be in multiple regions.  The following approach selects on arbitrary region for each customer:

```
    SELECT car.region, count(id) as totalcustomers,
           sum(ordertotal) as totaldolalrs
    FROM customers c JOIN
         (select ca.customerid, max(region) as region
          from customeraddresses ca join
               stateregions sr
                on sr.state = ca.state
          group by ca.customerid
         ) car
         ON c.id = car.customerid
    GROUP BY car.region ;
```

A more sophisticated approach is to assign customers to *all* regions they belong to, and then either prorate them or double count them.  The following prorates them:

```
    SELECT car.region, count(id) as totalcustomers,
           sum(ordertotal) as totaldolalrs
    FROM customers c JOIN
         (select ca.customerid, max(region) as region
          from customeraddresses ca join
               stateregions sr
                on sr.state = ca.state
         ) car

         ON c.id = car.customerid
    GROUP BY car.region ;
```

These queries are at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/297e86/25) SQL Fiddle.